# How to execute two queries in spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to set `row number` for each row in mysql via spark

```
SET @row_num = 0;
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number,t.* FROM table t
```

It's working fine in MySQL but from spark it's throwing an error

```
val setrownum = "SET property_key[=@row_num = 0]" // "SET @row_num = 0"
val rownum = "SELECT property_key := property_key + 1 as row_number,t.* FROM table t"
val setrowexe = spark.sql(setrownum)
val rownumexe = spark.sql(rownum)
```

I also tried

```
val setrownum = "SET property_key[=@row_num = 0];SELECT property_key := property_key + 1 as row_number,t.* FROM table t"
val setrowexe = spark.sql(setrownum) 
setrowexe.show()
```

but no luck. How to execute the above two queries in order to set table row number?

```
 SELECT property_key:=property_key+1 as rowid,d.* FROM destination d, (SELECT property_key[=@rowid:=0]) as init
```

This query executes in MySQL, but not via spark

Answer (score 0):

> above query executes in mysql but not via spark

And it won't. None of that supported in Spark SQL. Row number can be obtained using standard SQL with window functions.

```
SELECT row_number over (...) FROM table
```

Type of external database is not relevant. The only way to execute query on the source server is to use subquery in a dataframe definition, but it doesn't support extensions like this.

Comment: I'm having mysql as Database.

Comment: Any other way to achieve row number and table data in single query.